# How do you handle answers when requirements were originally unclear or changed?

Tags: discussion, edits, downvotes, unclear

This morning I was responding to this question

[Check a string order in a sentence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29649671/check-a-string-order-in-a-sentence)

It seemed like in that situation it was implied that they wanted to match whole words, not just substrings.  So I asked and this was the case.  I changed my answer and edited the question to be more clear.

Now the other answers that were previously completely legitimate no longer pertain to the question.  On the one hand, the responders made a perfectly reasonable response given the situation.  On the other hand, the responses no longer reflect an appropriate answer.

Should those answers be downvoted?

Answer (score 5):

If the question was *unclear* and was *clarified*, then that's a great change.  The question has been improved, hopefully to the point where it is now answerable.  If people tried to answer the unclear question (something they shouldn't have done in the first place) then they were providing unhelpful content.

If the original question was a clear, quality question, and it was edited into a completely different question (presumably because the author found the answer to their original question) then that is not an appropriate edit, and it should be rolled back.

Comment: So you saying that the other answers in this case should be downvoted?

Comment: @CarlosBribiescas Do you think that they're helpful or not helpful, given that they didn't understand the question and as a result posted an answer that doesn't answer the question?  Personally, I'd consider such a post not helpful, rather than being helpful.

Comment: I think you're oversimplifying and stating the correct answer in the extremes, where this specific situation lies more in the middle where its not obvious what the correct decision is.  The question seemed like an obvious question with clear requirements, but the requirements were subtly off.  Some answers are helpful but boolean incorrect.  If you look at the question now, someone simply nudged one of the responders and they corrected the answer in a way that such that it is now better response than mine.